# Google Calendar API V2 to V3 Migration Questions

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

Our organization has created a background batch server process that uses the Google Calendar V2 API to create calendars and manage permissions to the calendars. From an internal portal within organization, end-users will submit requests to create Google Calendars for internal sites within the portal. The requests are added to a batch queue and a Windows service processes the requests. When creating calendars, the process will first create a Google userid - using the provisioning API - that will be used as the owner of the calendar. That userid will be set as the owner when the calendar is created. The process will then add contribute and read permissions on the calendar ACL to allow other users in our organization to view it.

Since the batch process that runs to create the calendars is server based, no users interact directly with the process. The service reads end user requests directly from a queue stored in a database table. The batch process is running for the full domain, so it has to connect to Google with full domain privileges using our oauth domain key to generate oauth requests.

The following are the steps in our current process:

The first step is to create a calendar service using our domain OAuth consumer key and secret (retrieved from our domain admin console).

```
CalendarService _CalService = new CalendarService(“App Name”);

GOAuthRequestFactory  _requestFactory= new GOAuthRequestFactory(“Service Name”,  “App Name”);

_requestFactory.ConsumerKey = [Consumer Key from Domain OAuth security console] 
_requestFactory.ConsumerSecret = [Consumer Secret from Domain OAuth security console]

_CalService.RequestFactory = _requestFactory;
```

After getting the calendar service, we then perform actions on the calendar service, such as creating a new calendar:

```
CalendarEntry calendar = new CalendarEntry();
calendar.Title.Text = title;
calendar.Summary.Text = summary;
calendar.TimeZone = timeZone ?? _DefaultTimezone;
calendar.Location = new Where("", "", location ??)

Uri oUri = new OAuthUri(“https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full”, [user name of Google ID created as owner of calendar], [domain]);

CalendarEntry entry = (CalendarEntry)_CalService.Insert(oUri, calendar);
```

Our questions are as follows:

What is the equivalent process in the calendar API V3  to instantiate a calendar service using organization’s oauth domain key to generate oauth requests, as in the above example? Would this be an OAuth server account connection or something else? We read about a method using the OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator, but  we are not sure if this has been implemented or perhaps superseded with the Server Account connection.

Once we have a calendar connection, we need to create a calendar with a specific owner attached to it. In the above example, the OAuthURI handles setting the user name of the calendar owner. How is this handled in V3?

We noticed that URIs are used extensively in V2 service calls. How are they used in the V3 api, if at all? We haven’t found any V3 examples that reference URIs.

Aside from the V3 migration guide, are there any other repositories of examples using the V3 API with the .NET client?

Comment: Why don't you try to upgrade your library to the Google APIs client library for Calendar - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/calendar/v3? It looks like you are using the old GData library... All the library OAuth 2.0 documentation is available here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: Yes, we did upgrade to the V3 APIs and are in the process of converting our V2 code to V3 code. We are a bit uncertain about the correct approach for replacing the previous OAuth code in the example above that uses GOAuthRequestFactory and GAfE consumer key and secret. We are running a server batch process to update content for our Google apps domain, and we need to replace the GOAuthRequestFactory process. We saw some articles that said to use OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator, but it doesn't seem to be included in the google.apis.auth package. Should we use ServiceAccount option instead? Thanks

Comment: Like I mentioned, all OAuth 2.0 are summarized well in  developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth. By your description, it sounds like you DO need to use service account